# Get Only One Row For Each ID With the Highest Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have a query

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    mgr.MF_AGREEMENT_LGR TABLE1
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        MAX(VALUE_DATE) AS VALUE_DATE, 
        REGISTRATION_NO AS REGISTRATION_NO 
     FROM 
        mgr.MF_AGREEMENT_LGR 
     GROUP BY 
        REGISTRATION_NO) AS TABLE2 ON TABLE1.REGISTRATION_NO = TABLE2.REGISTRATION_NO
WHERE 
    TABLE1.VALUE_DATE = TABLE2.VALUE_DATE 
    AND TABLE1.TRX_CODE = 'LCLR'
ORDER BY 
    TABLE1.REGISTRATION_NO
```

This returns the rows with the latest date for each `REGISTRATION_CODE`. Some have like three or more results for each `REGISTRATION_CODE` because it has more than one transaction on the same date.

Also, each row has its `DOC_NO` field.

My question is, how am I going to get only one row from each `REGISTRATION_CODE` with the highest `DOC_NO`.

By the way, `DOC_NO` is a varchar.

Example value for this field is: `Amort 1, Amort 12, Amort 5`

If those examples are in one `REGISTRATION_CODE`, I only need the row with the highest amort which is Amort 12.

I am using a SQL Server 2000.

Comment: Is there a way to alter your tables? Getting the highest number from a varchar datatype column is going to be difficult. If you knew the max length of the numbers for `DOC_NO`, you could technically `SELECT RIGHT(DOC_NO, 2)` for example, then cast that as int, and order by `DESC`.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2000 has not been supported in *years*.  You really should upgrade to supported software.

You can get what you want with `not exists`:

```
SELECT al.*
FROM mgr.MF_AGREEMENT_LGR al
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM mgr.MF_AGREEMENT_LGR al2
                  WHERE al2.registration_no = al.registration_no and
                        (al2.date > al2.date or
                         al2.date = al.date and al2.DOC_NO > al.DOC_NO
                        )
                 ) AND
      al.TRX_CODE = 'LCLR';
```

You probably want the condition on `'LCLR'` in the subquery as well.  However, that is not in your original query, so I'm leaving it out.